CUDA Shared Memory Dynamic Memory Allocation
The problem I am having is that the matrixMulKernel_tiled kernel function is not performing any summing. I am unsure as to why the output matrix is consistently all zeros. Any thoughts? Please note, some function I left off for brevity.
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<cmath>
#include <math.h>

/******************************************************************************************************* */
/* Helper Functions*/
/* START */

//Must use cudaDeviceSynchronize() when measuring GPU kernel operations because CUDA kernel operations are non blocking. 

#define CHECK(call) { \
    const cudaError_t cuda_ret = call; \
    if(cuda_ret != cudaSuccess){\
        printf("Error: %s:%d, ", __FILE__, __LINE__); \
        printf("code: %d, reason:%s\n", cuda_ret, cudaGetErrorString(cuda_ret)); \
        exit(-1); \
    } \
}

int calculateTileSize(int sharedMemBytesPerBlock){
    int maxTileSize = sqrt((sharedMemBytesPerBlock / 8));
    int factor = maxTileSize/16;

    if(maxTileSize/16 == 0)
        return maxTileSize%16;

    return factor*16;
}

/* END */
/* Helper Functions*/
/******************************************************************************************************* */





/******************************************************************************************************* */
/* Matrix Multiplication Functions*/
/* START */



__global__ void matrixMulKernel_1thread1element(float* a_d, float* b_d, float* c_d, unsigned int m, unsigned int k, unsigned int n){
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y; 
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    float sum = 0.0f;
    if(col < n && row < m) {
        for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            sum += a_d[row * k + i] * b_d[i * n + col];
        }
        c_d[row * n + col] = sum;
    }
} 

__global__ void matrixMulKernel_tiled(float* a_d, float* b_d, float* c_d, unsigned int m, unsigned int k, unsigned int n, int tile_size, int As_size, int Bs_size){

    extern __shared__ float As_Bs[];

    float *A_s = (float *) As_Bs;
    float *B_s = (float *) As_Bs + As_size;

    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    float sum = 0.0f;

    int condition = (int) ceilf(k/(float)tile_size);

    for(int tile = 0; tile < condition; tile++) {

        if( tile * tile_size + threadIdx.x < k && row < m){
            A_s[threadIdx.y * tile_size + threadIdx.x] = a_d[row*n + tile*tile_size + threadIdx.x];
        }
        else{
            A_s[threadIdx.y * tile_size + threadIdx.x] = 0;
        }

        if( tile * tile_size + threadIdx.y < k && col < n){
            B_s[threadIdx.y * tile_size + threadIdx.x] = b_d[(tile*tile_size + threadIdx.y)*n + col];
        }
        else{
            B_s[threadIdx.y * tile_size + threadIdx.x] = 0;
        }

        __syncthreads();

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < tile_size; i++) {
            sum += A_s[threadIdx.y * tile_size + i] * B_s[i * tile_size + threadIdx.x];
        }

        __syncthreads();
    }

    if(row < m && col < n)
        c_d[row*n + col] = sum;
} 

/* Matrix Multiplication Functions*/
/* END */
/******************************************************************************************************* */



void basicSgemm_d_1thread1element(float* a_h, float* b_h, float* c_h, unsigned int m, unsigned int k, unsigned int n){

    // (1) allocate device memory for arrays x_d, y_d, z_d
    float *a_d, *b_d, *c_d;
    cudaMalloc((void**) &a_d, sizeof(float)*m*k);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &b_d, sizeof(float)*k*n);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &c_d, sizeof(float)*m*n);

    // (2) copy matrices a_h and b_h to device memory a_d and b_d, respectively
    cudaMemcpy(a_d, a_h, sizeof(float)*m*k, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(b_d, b_h, sizeof(float)*k*n, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // (3) call kernel to launch a grid of threads to perform the matrix multiplcation on GPU
    dim3 gridDim((n + 16 - 1) / 16, (m + 16 - 1) / 16);
    dim3 blockDim(16, 16);

    double start_time = myCPUTimer();
    matrixMulKernel_1thread1element<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(a_d, b_d, c_d, m, k, n);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    double end_time = myCPUTimer();
    double elapsed_time = end_time - start_time;

    printf("\nElapsed time of 1 thread 1 output element: %f s\n", elapsed_time);

    // (4) Copy the result data from device memory of array c_d to host memory of array c_h
    cudaMemcpy(c_h, c_d, sizeof(float)*m*n, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < m*n; i++){
        printf("%f ", c_h[i]);
    }

    // (5) free device memory of a_d, b_d, and c_d 
    cudaFree(a_d);
    cudaFree(b_d);
    cudaFree(c_d);
}

void basicSgemm_d_tiled(float* a_h, float* b_h, float* c_h, unsigned int m, unsigned int k, unsigned int n){

    // (1) allocate device memory for arrays x_d, y_d, z_d
    float *a_d, *b_d, *c_d;
    cudaMalloc((void**) &a_d, sizeof(float)*m*k);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &b_d, sizeof(float)*k*n);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &c_d, sizeof(float)*m*n);

    // (2) copy matrices a_h and b_h to device memory a_d and b_d, respectively
    cudaMemcpy(a_d, a_h, sizeof(float)*m*k, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(b_d, b_h, sizeof(float)*k*n, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // (3) call kernel to launch a grid of threads to perform the matrix multiplcation on GPU
    cudaDeviceProp devProp;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&devProp, 0);
    unsigned int sharedMemBytesPerBlock = devProp.sharedMemPerBlock;
    int TILE_SIZE = calculateTileSize(sharedMemBytesPerBlock);

    int As_size = TILE_SIZE * TILE_SIZE;

    dim3 gridDim((n + TILE_SIZE - 1) / TILE_SIZE, (m + TILE_SIZE - 1) / TILE_SIZE);
    dim3 blockDim(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
    size_t dynamicallyConfiguredSharedMemorySize = 2 * TILE_SIZE * TILE_SIZE * sizeof(float);
    printf("Grid Dimensions: %d, %d\n", (n + TILE_SIZE - 1) / TILE_SIZE, (m + TILE_SIZE - 1) / TILE_SIZE);

    double start_time = myCPUTimer();
    matrixMulKernel_tiled<<<gridDim, blockDim, dynamicallyConfiguredSharedMemorySize>>>(a_d, b_d, c_d, m, k, n, TILE_SIZE, As_size, As_size);
    CHECK(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    double end_time = myCPUTimer();
    double elapsed_time = end_time - start_time;

    printf("\n\nElapsed time of 1 thread 1 output element with shared memory: %f s\n", elapsed_time);

    // (4) Copy the result data from device memory of array c_d to host memory of array c_h
    cudaMemcpy(c_h, c_d, sizeof(float)*m*n, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < m*n; i++){
        printf("%f ", c_h[i]);
    }

    // (5) free device memory of a_d, b_d, and c_d 
    cudaFree(a_d);
    cudaFree(b_d);
    cudaFree(c_d);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int m = atoi(argv[1]);
    int k = atoi(argv[2]);
    int n = atoi(argv[3]);

    srand(time(0));

    // matrix  is of size  × , matrix  is of size  × , and matrix  is of size  × .
    float* a_h = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*m*k);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < m*k; i++) a_h[i] = rand()%100/100.0;

    float* b_h = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*k*n);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < k*n; i++) b_h[i] = rand()%100/100.0;

    float* c_h = (float*) calloc(m*n, sizeof(float));


    int precision = calculatePrecision(m, k, n);

    printf("\nPrecision Threshold: %d decimal places.\n", precision);
    printf("\nMatrix Dimensions: \n");
    printf("\tA: %d x %d\n", m, k);
    printf("\tB: %d x %d\n", k, n);
    printf("\tC: %d x %d\n", m, n);

    bool testsPassed = true;

    basicSgemm_d_1thread1element(a_h, b_h, c_h, m, k, n);
    if(!verify(c_h, cpu_result, m, n, precision)) testsPassed = false;

    basicSgemm_d_tiled(a_h, b_h, c_h, m, k, n);
    // if(!verify(c_h, cpu_result, m, n, precision)) testsPassed = false;

    if(testsPassed){
        printf("\nVerifying Results... Tests Passed!\n");
    }else{
        printf("\nVerifying Results... Tests Failed!\n");
    }
    
    free(a_h);
    free(b_h);
    free(c_h);
    free(cpu_result);

    return 0;
}

I have double checked my boundary conditions and device properties and made sure they are right but to no avail. Is there a CUDA API call that I am missing?

Call CHECK(cudaGetLastError()); after every kernel launch (before synchronization) to check if the launch was successful. For completeness you should also CHECK all other CUDA runtime calls.

Please avoid using floating point math functions for integer calculations. It is expensive and hard to argue about due to rounding errors. For example ceiling division should be done as int ceil_div(int dividend, int divisor) { return dividend / divisor + (dividend % divisor != 0); } You are sometimes  using (dividend + divisor - 1) / divisor which is fine as long as the inputs are not big enough to cause overflow. The integer squareroot is not as basic, but you can find plenty of options on Wikipedia.

I don't think if(maxTileSize / 16 == 0) return maxTileSize % 16; makes any sense. In this case maxTileSize is already smaller than 16, so the remainder operation is doing nothing.

In your code, calculateTileSize can return a number higher than 32, which causes your total block size to be over 1024, the maximum limit of threads for a block per the CUDA programming guide. Therefore, your kernel launch fails and the code is never executed.
Modifying calculateTileSize to return the minimum between its current value and 32 (square root of 1024) addresses the issue (confirmed locally).
For future reference, in order to check for possible errors, you can run your program under NVIDIA's compute-sanitizer. Example here that allowed me to figure out the issue:
$ compute-sanitizer ./test 8 8 8
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER

Matrix Dimensions:
        A: 8 x 8
        B: 8 x 8
        C: 8 x 8
...
Grid Dimensions: 1, 1
========= Program hit cudaErrorInvalidConfiguration (error 9) due to "invalid configuration argument" on CUDA API call to cudaLaunchKernel.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========         Host Frame: matrixMulKernel_tiled(float*, float*, float*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, int) in test.cu:58 [0x9cfe] in test
...

